# Using NSURLCache to preload local assets for UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlcache

I'm working on an iOS application that displays locally-stored content (HTML files) in a UIWebView.

The problem is that some of the assets referenced from the HTMLs (for example fonts and images) take quite a while when loaded for the first time. I assume that the solution to the problem is to somehow cache these assets with NSURLCache before they're used in a UIWebView, but this seems to cause some trouble.

What I have tried so far:

- Subclassing NSURLCache and overriding `cachedResponseForRequest` so that it returns a response with the asset preloaded in an NSData object. Preloading is done in the `init` method. The overridden `cachedResponseForRequest` seems to get called but for some reason the UIWebView still loads the asset from the file system.
- Using `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` to cache NSCachedURLResponse objects containing the assets before they're used in a UIWebView.

Neither of these seems to help. Any advice for where to look for the problem?

Comment: Hey man, were you able to solve this?